# JavaScript: Match a regex and return only part of the result?

Tags: javascript

I know this is possible but I can't find the answer with the Google keywords I'm using, so I'm asking this in the hope it helps someone else too.

I'd like to regex match a substring but only return part of that substring.

Here's my attempt:

```
const t = "The 2 items contained 150 calories";
t.match(/(\d+) calorie/g).replace(" calorie", "");
```

This returns `150 calorie` but what I want is just `150`.

I can hack it with `t.match(/(\d+) calorie/g)[0].replace(" calorie", "")` but perhaps there's a way to do it just with regexes?

Comment: With your current regex you can also just grab out the capture group. `t.match(/(\d+) calorie/g)[1]` Because `\d+` is in parenthesis it is captured as a group at the 1 index. See https://regex101.com/r/5aWBds/1

Comment: @ug_ that's true when the `g` flag is not used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex lookaheads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups):

```js
const t = "The 2 items contained 150 calories";
const result = t.match(/(\d+)(?= calorie)/g)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, although you can't use a `.replace` after a `.match` because the latter returns an array like object. Remove the `g` flag, and get the first capture group with `[1]`:

```js
const t = "The 2 items contained 150 calories";
const num = t.match(/(\d+) calorie/)[1];
console.log(num);
```

BTW, if you are concerned about a string not matching your regex use this instead:

```
const t = "The 2 items contained 150 calories";
const m = t.match(/(\d+) calorie/);
const num = m ? m[1] : null;
console.log(num);
```

You can also use a positive lookahead as @Live bug help explained, but please note that that is not universally supported, notably Safari.

Comment: You can also swap it around; instead of `string.match(regexp)` you can do `regexp.exec(string)`: `const t = "The 2 items contained 150 calories"; const result = /(\d+) calorie/g.exec(t);`

Comment: @Sly_cardinal: Yup, although you still need two statements to account for no match

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know JavaScript, but I think regex is equal as in python. In my example ‘t’ is your text string.

Explanation:

\d+ Match 1+ digits (Or \d for a single digit)

(?:/\d+)? Optionally match / and 1+ digits

(?= Positive lookahead to assert what is directly at the right is

\s?calories?\b Match an optional whitspace char followed by calories or calories

) Close the lookahead

code:

```
result = re.findall(r"\d+(?:/\d+)?(?=\s?calories?\b)", t)
print(result) # will print 150 only
```

Source: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892144/20851944)